# Angular 12 generates an enormous vendor.xxx.js.map file (6.3MB), but no vendor code seems to be mapped

Tags: angular, typescript, source-maps

When served locally via `ng serve`, I can access my Angular project via localhost, and in the browser console sourcemaps let me see all the way down to into `node_modules`, so even vendor code can be seen mapped back to original, un-minified TypeScript code:

[image: Browser console screenshot showing TypeScript source]

I'd like to be able to retain that same level of source mapping for debugging deployed production code. But no matter how I configure `angular.json` for production, when I do a production build and move the code to a real server, the best I get is minified JavaScript for my npm dependencies:

[image: Browser console screenshot with only minified JavaScript source]

The sourcemaps work for project-specific code, but nothing else, even though there's a huge vendor.xxx.js.map file. In my `angular.json` file I've done everything I think I should have to do (and more than I want to do) to keep full source mapping alive, but none of it has helped so far.

```
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "1.3mb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": {
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": true,
                "vendor": true
              },
              "namedChunks": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
```

I'm definitely changing the right part of my `angular.json` file because I see the effects of whether or not the file names are hashed, if there's a separate vendor file or not, etc.

Anything else I can do to make my sourcemaps work to a deep level, and not just for project-specific code?

Comment: Why do you have optimization disabled for prod? Also, your fileReplacements look wrong

Comment: I really don't want to disable optimization, I was just trying to test if optimization was messing up proper sourcemap generation. Same thing with the strangeness of the `fileReplacements`. What I did was try to make the prod build as much like the dev build as possible, hoping to find a place where full sourcemapping worked again. Once I find (if I find!) a solution, then I'll try to put back all of the optimization that I can put back again.